# Generating a mutation frequency on a DNA Strand using Python

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

I would like to input a DNA sequence and make some sort of generator that yields sequences that have a certain frequency of mutations. For instance, say I have the DNA strand "ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC", and I want to create mutations with a T->A frequency of 5%. How would I go about to creating this? I know that creating random mutations can be done with a code like this:

```
import random
def mutate(string, mutation, threshold):
    dna = list(string)
    for index, char in enumerate(dna):
        if char in mutation:
            if random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return ''.join(dna)
```

But what I am truly not sure how to do is make a fixed mutation frequency. Anybody know how to do that? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So should the formatting look like this if I'm using a byte array, because I'm getting an error:

```
import random

dna = "ATGTCGTACGTTTGACGTAGAG"

def mutate(dna, mutation, threshold):
    dna = bytearray(dna) #if you don't want to modify the original
    for index in range(len(dna)):
        if dna[index] in mutation and random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return dna
```

mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("my dna now:", dna)

error: "TypeError: string argument without an encoding"

**EDIT 2:**

```
import random

myDNA = bytearray("ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC")

def mutate(dna, mutation, threshold):
    dna = myDNA # if you don't want to modify the original
    for index in range(len(dna)):
        if dna[index] in mutation and random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return dna

mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("my dna now:", dna)
```

yields an error

Comment: Thanks. If I was going to use a byte array, do I convert the string to that or what? I'm not completely familiar with it.

Comment: I am sorry, but here are 3 solutions: either use `dna = bytearray(b"ATGTCGTACGTTTGACGTAGAG")`, change `dna = bytearray(dna)` to `dna = bytearray(dna, "ascii")` (this requires the first parameter of mutate to be a string) or you just use your code of the function mutate (this works too) and leave the rest unchanged.

Comment: Your second edit is wrong in several ways: myDNA cannot be created, because if you want to create a bytearray, you have to use bytes or a string with an encoding, so `bytearray(b"...")` or `bytearray("...", "ascii")`. Also the line `dna = myDNA` is questionable. The function recieves the parameter dna, so to not use the original passed to the function you overwrite dna (which refers to the original) with a copy of the original, so write `dna = bytearray(dna)`. There are several mistakes in the for-loop, all done by me, so copy my updated code.

Comment: The function call uses `dna` as a parameter, but you never defined `dna`, use `newDNA = mutate(myDNA, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)`, to store the result. To print the result convert it to a string: `print("My DNA now:", newDNA.decode("ascii"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked me about a function that prints all possible mutations, here it is. The number of outputs grows exponentially with your input data length, so the function only prints the possibilities and does not store them somehow (that could consume very much memory). I created a recursive function, this function should not be used with very large input, I also will add a non-recursive function that should work without problems or limits.

```
def print_all_possibilities(dna, mutations, index = 0, print = print):
    if index < 0: return #invalid value for index

    while index < len(dna):
        if chr(dna[index]) in mutations:
            print_all_possibilities(dna, mutations, index + 1)
            dnaCopy = bytearray(dna)
            dnaCopy[index] = ord(mutations[chr(dna[index])])
            print_all_possibilities(dnaCopy, mutations, index + 1)

            return
        index += 1
    print(dna.decode("ascii"))

# for testing
print_all_possibilities(bytearray(b"AAAATTTT"), {"A": "T"})
```

This works for me on python 3, I also can explain the code if you want.
Note: This function requires a bytearray as given in the function test.

**Explanation:**
This function searches for a place in dna where a mutation can happen, it starts at index, so it normally begins with 0 and goes to the end. That's why the while-loop, which increases index every time the loop is executed, is for (it's basically a normal iteration like a for loop). If the function finds a place where a mutation can happen (`if chr(dna[index]) in mutations:`), then it copies the dna and lets the second one mutate (`dnaCopy[index] = ord(mutations[chr(dna[index])])`, Note that a bytearray is an array of numeric values, so I use chr and ord all the time to change between string and int). After that the function is called again to look for more possible mutations, so the functions look again for possible mutations in both possible dna's, but they skip the point they have already scanned, so they begin at `index + 1`. After that the order to print is passed to the called functions print_all_possibilities, so we don't have to do anything anymore and quit the executioning with `return`. If we don't find any mutations anymore we print our possible dna, because we don't call the function again, so no one else would do it.
It may sound complicated, but it is a more or less elegant solution. Also, to understand a recursion you have to understand a recursion, so don't bother yourself if you don't understand it for now. It could help if you try this out on a sheet of paper: Take an easy dna string "TTATTATTA"  with the possible mutation "A" -> "T" (so we have 8 possible mutations) and do this: Go through the string from left to right and if you find a position, where the sequence can mutate (here it is just the "A"'s), write this string down again, this time let the string mutate at the given position, so that your second string is slightly different from the original. In the original and the copy, mark how far you came (maybe put a "|" after the letter you let mutate) and repeat this procedure with the copy as new original. If you don't find any possible mutation, then underline the string (This is the equivalent to printing it). At the end you should have 8 different strings all underlined. I hope that can help to understand it.

**EDIT:** Here is the non-recursive function:

```
def print_all_possibilities(dna, mutations, printings = -1, print = print):
    mut_possible = []
    for index in range(len(dna)):
        if chr(dna[index]) in mutations: mut_possible.append(index)

    if printings < 0: printings = 1 << len(mut_possible)
    for number in range(min(printings, 1 << len(mut_possible)):
        dnaCopy = bytearray(dna) # don't change the original
        counter = 0
        while number:
            if number & (1 << counter):
                index = mut_possible[counter]
                dnaCopy[index] = ord(mutations[chr(dna[index])])
                number &= ~(1 << counter)
            counter += 1

        print(dnaCopy.decode("ascii"))

# for testing
print_all_possibilities(bytearray(b"AAAATTTT"), {"A": "T"})
```

This function comes with an additional parameter, which can control the number of maximum outputs, e.g.

```
print_all_possibilities(bytearray(b"AAAATTTT"), {"A": "T"}, 5)
```

will only print 5 results.

**Explanation:**
If your dna has x possible positions where it can mutate, you have 2 ^ x possible mutations, because at every place the dna can mutate or not. This function finds all positions where your dna can mutate and stores them in `mut_possible` (that's the code of the for-loop). Now `mut_possible` contains all positions where the dna can mutate and so we have 2 ^ `len(mut_possible)` (`len(mut_possible)` is the number of elements in mut_possible) possible mutations. I wrote `1 << len(mut_possible)`, it's the same, but faster. If `printings` is a negative number the function will decide to print all possibilities and set printings to the number of possibilities. If printings is positive, but lower than the number of possibilities, then the function will print only `printings` mutations, because `min(printings, 1 << len(mut_possible))` will return the smaller number, which is `printings`. Else, the function will print out all possibilities. Now we have `number` to go through `range(...)` and so this loop, which prints one mutation every time, will execute the desired number of times. Also, number will increase by one every time. (e.g., range(4) is similar! to [0, 1, 2, 3]). Next we use number to create a mutation. To understand this step you have to understand a binary number. If our number is 10, it's in binary 1010. These numbers tell us at which places we have to modify out code of dna (`dnaCopy`). The first bit is a 0, so we don't modify the first position where a mutation can happen, the next bit is a 1, so we modify this position, after that there is a 0 and so on... To "read" the bits we use the variable `counter`. `number & (1 << counter)` will return a non-zero value if the `counter`th bit is set, so if this bit is set we modify our dna at the `counter`th position where a mutation can happen. This is written in mut_possible, so our desired position is `mut_possible[counter]`. After we mutated our dna at that position we set the bit to 0 to show that we already modified this position. That is done with `number &= ~(1 << counter)`. After that we increase counter to look at the other bits. The while-loop will only continue to execute if number is not 0, so if number has at least one bit set (if we have to modify at least one position of dna). After we modified our dnaCopy the while-loop is finished and we print our result.

I hope these explanations could help. I see that you are new to python, so take yourself time to let that sink in and contact me if you have any further questions.

Comment: Thanks!! :) could you explain the bytearray code, please?

Comment: @user3670902 I updated the answer, which now contains the explanations.

Comment: actually, one more question for further thought: could I combine the two pieces of code you provided and get both a 5% mutation frequency as all the strands with these possible mutations? You gave me a code that could work for outputting all the possible strands of a certain mutation, but how do I add the parameter of a fixed mutation frequency to that code, specifically?

Comment: As fas as I understood you, you want a function that make both, mutates the dna and gives all possible mutations. Is this even correct? I would rather use both functions indendent from each other, because the second function creates mutations without knowing their chance of happening. Another way to write the program would be an object orientated way. Links to that topic would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming and https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html . In general you would create a dna-object, which would perform these operations on itself.

Comment: ok, got it. I was thinking of combining the functions, but it may be cleaner to keep them separate

Comment: I've been trying to use the two functions, but I just don't know how. They keep acting independently of each other. Could you show me the best way to do this? I have no idea how to use the two functions on a single strand.

Comment: Keep in mind what each function does and what each function returns. `mutate` takes a dna and returns another dna. `print_all_posibilities` takes a dna and returns nothing, but prints all possible mutations. Both functions do not modify the dna you give it. I think you want this: `dna = bytearray(b"GATACA")
one_mutation = mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("This are all possible mutations of " + dna.decode("ascii"))
print_all_possiblities(dna, {"A": "T"})
print("We got " + dna.decode("ascii"))`

Comment: `random.random()` returns a random number beetween 0.0 and 1.0. `random.random() < 1` will return `True` in 100% of all calls, so `random.random() < 0.05` returns `True` in 5% of all calls.

Answer (score 0):

After what I read this question seems easy to answer. The chance is high that I misunderstood something, so please correct me if I am wrong.

If you want a chance of 5% to change a T with an A, then you should write

```
mutate(yourString, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
```

I also suggest you to use a bytearray instead of a string. A bytearray is similar to a string, it can only contain bytes (values from 0 to 255) while a string can contain more characters, but a bytearray is mutable. By using a bytearray you don't need to create you temporary list or to join it in the end. If you do that, your code looks like this:

```
import random
def mutate(dna, mutation, threshold):
    if isinstance(dna, str):
        dna = bytearray(dna, "utf-8")
    else:
        dna = bytearray(dna)

    for index in range(len(dna)):
        if chr(dna[index]) in mutation and random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = ord(mutation[chr(dna[index])])

    return dna

dna = "ATGTCGTACGTTTGACGTAGAG"
print("DNA first:", dna)
newDNA = mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("DNA now:", newDNA.decode("ascii")) #use decode to make newDNA a string
```

After all the stupid problems I had with the bytearray version, here is the version that operates on strings:

```
import random
def mutate(string, mutation, threshold):
    dna = list(string)
    for index, char in enumerate(dna):
        if char in mutation:
            if random.random() < threshold:
                dna[index] = mutation[char]

    return ''.join(dna)

dna = "ATGTCGTACGTTTGACGTAGAG"
print("DNA first:", dna)
newDNA = mutate(dna, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("DNA now:", newDNA)
```

If you use the string version with larger input the computation time will be bigger as well as the memory used. The bytearray-version will be the best when you want to do this with much larger input.

Comment: ok. but where would I place the first bit of code? After the loop?

Comment: What code do you mean? If you mean your program code, just add this after my code. E.g.
`#my code...
myDNA = bytearray("ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC")
mutate(myDNA, {"A": "T"}, 0.05)
print("my dna now:", myDNA)`

Comment: wait... I tried to run the program, but I got the error I added above in my edits.

Comment: Remember, if you want to use my code you have to use a bytearray, otherwise it will throw an error. If you want to use your code, then you can use the code I posted in my commend above. If you do that, then you can replace `myDNA = bytearray("ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC")` with `myDNA = "ATGTCGTCACACACCGCAGATCCGTGTTTGAC"`

Comment: ok. I made some slight changes (see edit 2), but I get the same error

Comment: @user3670902 I am sorry for the inconveniences I caused, I updated my answer and it works now (for python 3).

Comment: oh, thanks. Yeah, it was Python 3. One more question, and I'm not sure if you can answer this, but is there a possible way to make on output of all the possible strings that one can make with the 5% mutation I mentioned earlier? Thanks